# Sample LAMMPS file for graphene growth on a metal surface

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, surfaces, graphene, software-input-file-request

I am working with graphene growth on metal substrates. But I need some sample files to know if I am doing it in the right way because running multiple simulations in LAMMPS takes a lot of time. Can anyone help me in that? It will be really helpful.

Any sample file regarding graphene growth will do (Prefered method: Chemical Vapour Deposition). **Is there any place where I might be able to find such a sample LAMMPS file?**

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: By the way, there is a LAMMPS chat room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps. Please check it out and say hello at least once so that you become a member of the room!

Comment: Abdullah, it's been almost a year! I'm so sorry that you didn't get an answer yet! Are you still looking for this sample LAMMPS file? If you got the problem solved, can you post a self-answer with the LAMMPS file you used? Where else have you asked about this problem so far?